# a4j:support after h:inputText value change doesn't work

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

can anyone figure out why the `h:outputText` doesn't get refreshed after inputText value change?
I've tried both `onkeyup` and `onchange` and both don't affect..

When I do some other thing that makes the page refresh, the `h:outputText` is rendered correctly so it's only a matter of getting the ajax to actually rerender the component.

```
<h:inputText autocomplete="off" styleClass="propertyInput"
    value="#{activesyncDM.userNameDomain}" validator="#{activesyncDM.validate}"
    id="userNameDomain" dir="ltr">
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="domainNameSlash"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText id="domainNameSlash" value="\\"  rendered="#{!empty activesyncDM.userNameDomain}"/>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

besides putting `ajaxSingle="true"` for `a4j:support` which is mentioned by Cristian , the `id` attribute in HTML code  rendered by the JSF may not be the same as the ID value you set in `<h:outputText>` . Richfaces provides a function `rich:clientId('id')`  to get these dynamic ID generated by JSF . This function is invoked via the EL expression.

So , you can try :

`<a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="#{rich:clientId('domainNameSlash')}"/>`

Answer (score 3):

You have to send the value of inputText to the backing bean in order the outputText to reflect the changes so you should put: `ajaxSingle="true"` for `a4j:support`

`<a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="domainNameSlash"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Cristian, I can see that the validation is run now so that's a step forward but the h:outputText still doesn't get rerendered...

Comment: I am sure it sounds a little bit silly but please make sure it passes the validation. Otherwise the bean will not have the new value. If it still does not work can you put all this code in an `a4j:form` or `a4j:region`?